# Pre-configured AVDs to match real devices

Tags: device, android

Looks like Android SDK doesn't come with any AVDs byt default. We need to create a new custom one. But I was wondering if there are pre-configured AVDs available to use that matches exact devices, for example LG P500.

Comment: An AVD stands for Android Virtual Device which is an Emulator configuration that's modeled after a particular device.  This is a dev question and belongs over at SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Tea Vui Huang's AVD list](http://web.archive.org/web/20100625031154/http://teavuihuang.com/android/)** had some good ones (link is to Wayback Machine).  They are pre-packaged with the settings as well as skins.  There are screenshots and downloads all available there.  There's not an LG P500, but quite a few others that would be similar.

Example
[image]

Comment: Wow ! This is an awesome list.